# Close and open a new browser in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a script which needs the browser that selenium is operating close and re-open, without losing its cookies.

Any idea on how to go about it?

Basically, it's a check to see that if the user opens and closes his browser, his cookies stay intact.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `stop` and `start` commands. You will need to ensure that you are not clearing cookies between sessions, and depending on the browser you're launching you may also need to use the `-browserSessionReuse` command line option.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of the browser and not your concern: If there is a bug in the browser, then there is little you can do. If you need to know whether a certain version of the browser works correctly, then define a manual test (write a document that explains the steps), do it once and record the result somewhere (like "Browser XXX version YYY works").

When you know that a certain browser (version) works, then that's not going to change, so there is no need to repeat the test.

Comment: i think he was more concerned about setting the cookie expiration settings right.